# Adding multiple photos in rails_admin via paperclip - No route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I added paperclip and rails_admin to my project to be able to attach multiple pictues. Pictures are attached to articles model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150> "},
                            :url  => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                            :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  has_attached_file :image, 
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
    :url  => "/images/:id/:filename"

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

I followed this tutorial to enable multiple uploads (with html5) - [Tutorial](http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/)

So, i create a gem and edited the following

```
views/multiple_upload.html.haml

= simple_form_for(rails_admin.multiple_upload_url(@abstract_model.to_param), html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
  = f.input :article_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :name => "article_id", :value => @object.id }
  = file_field_tag('article_pictures_file', multiple: true, name: "article[pictures_attributes][][file]")
  = f.submit :submit, value: 'Upload', name: 'Upload', :class => 'btn btn-primary'




**lib/rails_admin_multiple_upload.rb**

require "rails_admin_multiple_upload/engine"

module RailsAdminMultipleUpload
end

require 'rails_admin/config/actions'

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class MultipleUpload < Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
        register_instance_option :member do
          true
        end

        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-upload'
        end

        register_instance_option :http_methods do
          [:get, :post]
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          Proc.new do
            @response = {}

            if request.post?
              @article = Article.find_by_id(params[:article_id])
              @article.update_attribute(:pictures_attributes, params[:article][:pictures_attributes])
            end

            render :action => @action.template_name
end
end
end
end
end
end
```

Then, I changed rails_admin.rb in my app:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new

    **multiple_upload do
      only Article
    end**

    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app
  end
end
```

When i go to /admin panel and click 'Multiple upload for Article' i get this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /article/16/multiple_upload
No route matches {:action=>"multiple_upload", :controller=>"rails_admin/main", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :model_name=>"article"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Anybody knows whats wrong here? Or should I use a different way to add multi-pic-add function?

THX

Comment: do you find a solution for this? i want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
= simple_form_for(rails_admin.multiple_upload_url(@abstract_model.to_param, id: @object.id), html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
```